# Advice for ignoring ds_store file when uploading files to jupyter

Tags: python, pandas

I was wondering if anyone had some advice on how deal with the ds.store file that is automatically created by apple for each folder when uploading  data. Does everyone just write an if statement:

```
 for i in files:
    if file == '.DS_Store'
       continue

    upload file...
```

or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: The file is `.DS_Store`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to ignore or skip all hidden files
Assuming you want to ignore all files that start with .:

```
import os


root = "/Users/yourname/Desktop/py scripts"
for item in os.listdir(root):
if not item.startswith('.') and os.path.isfile(os.path.join(root, item)):
 print item
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to ensure you skip all hidden files use something like `filename.startswith('.')`